# regular expression not giving complete match

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to find this in the string with regex.

```
  : [J, BASIC]
  ? [CINTERMEDIATE]
  : [D,MEDIUM]
```

the first character can be either **':' or '?'**
then there is a white-space,then square brackets 
within the square brackets there is two text block separated by a comma and/or white space. the comma or white space may or may not be present

Here is what i have written to find this

```
regex = re.compile('[:|?\s[\w[,\s]?\w]]+')
```

but it finds only

```
'C]'
'E]'
'M]'
```

Comment: you forgot to escape some `[`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is not handling `[`'s as literals.. they are taken as special characters (character set)

You can use the following:

```
[:?]\s*\[\w+(\s*,\s*)?\w+\]
```

Explanation:

- `[:?]` the first character can be either ':' or '?'
- `\s*\[` then there is a white-space,then square brackets
- `\w+(\s*,\s*)?\w+`  within the square brackets there is two text block separated by a comma and/or white space (with optional comma and space)
- `\]` close bracket

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fD6tO4/2)

**Edit:** If you want to capture the match you can use :

```
([:?]\s*\[\w+(?:\s*,\s*)?\w+\])
```

Comment: `\s*` This part will match weather it's `: [J, BASIC]` or `:[J, BASIC]`

Comment: what is the use of pipe '|' then ?  i saw it somewhere for 'or' condition

Comment: also according to https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html  Metacharacters are not active inside classes. For example, [akm$] will match any of the characters 'a', 'k', 'm', or '$'; '$' is usually a metacharacter, but inside a character class it’s stripped of its special nature.the same won't apply to '[' ?

Comment: look at the output in DEMO,yours only matches comma. 
[:?]\s*\[\w+\s*,*\s*\w+\] this works better

Comment: @Ankit .. pipe is used as an `or` operator outside character class `[..]` (character class by default takes `or` of characters in it). also.. `[:?]\s*[\w+\s*,*\s*\w+]` shouldnot be used, i suggest you to read about character set [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: yeah but if you look at the match information in DEMO it shows only two groups
`MATCH 1
1. [4-6] `, `
`MATCH 2
1. [35-36] `,`` when I use span() it does not give me start and end indices of each of them which I need.

Comment: yes it works great .can you explain what you changed?and what's the meaning of `(?:`

Comment: `(?:<something>)` means `match <something> but dont capture it in a group`.. previously i was capturing `\s*,\s*`.. now i kept it in non capturing group (`(?: <something>)`) and captured the whole match (starting to end)

Answer (score 2):

```
[:?]\s\[[^\]]+?\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/6lYU40QL99Y0ipK1)

Answer (score 2):

```
[:?]\s+\[[^, \]]*[, ]?[^\]]*\]
```

You can try this pattern.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/bN8dL3/8#python